# How to perform action for a custom UITableViewCell inside my viewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, ios10

I have a custom cell that has a xib, this cell contains a button, when the button is pressed I want to do an action , but not inside my custom cell class but from inside the viewcontroller that contains the tableview of the custom cell, any help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you should write a protocol for example:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
  func doAnyAction(cell:CustomUITableViewCell)
}
```

Then inside your custom cell class declare:

```
weak var delegate:CustomCellDelegate?
```

and inside your IBAction in the custom cell class:

```
@IBAction func onButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.doAnyAction(cell: self)
 //here we say that the responsible class for this action is the one that implements this delegate and we pass the custom cell to it.
}
```

Now in your viewController:

1- Make your view controller implement CustomCellDelegate.
2- In your cellForRow when declaring the cell don't forget to write:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

3- Finally call the function in your viewcontroller:

```
func doAnyAction(cell: CustomUITableViewCell) {
    let row = cell.indexPath(for: cell)?.row
  //do whatever you want

    }
}
```

Comment: Passing cell to the `viewController` will create a memory retain cycle.

Comment: but declaring the delegate as weak var won't do

Comment: Writing cell.delegate = self giving me the error :Cannot assign value of type 'Controller' to type 'CustomCellDelegate?'

Comment: @iPeter You have to implement this protocol by the controller first:
  class Controller:CustomCellDelegate {

  }

Comment: @iPeter I had the same error too. Just add the protocol function to the view controller and it should go away

Answer (score 4):

You can use delegate pattern. Create a custom protocol.

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
func buttonTapped() }
```

and on tableview cell conform delegate

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate!

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate.buttonTapped()
} }
```

table view data source

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

conform protocol(delegate) from table view controller or view controller

```
extension TestViewController: CustomTableViewCellDelegate {
func buttonTapped() {
    print("do something...")
} }
```

Comment: Hey guys, i would like to do the opposite, so i can check the current cell being visible in the UITableViewCell subclass.  im calling a download img func in the uitableviewcell subclass so i need to check when updating that that the image is setting to the correct cell only..

Comment: hi @lorenzogonzalez you can use cell's tag property for check.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the `UIButton` in your `cellForRowAtIndexpath`. 
Then write the following code.

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside). 

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton){
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add action for button from `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method from your viewController.

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row;

cell.btn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleButtonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside).
```

Write selector function in your view Controller:

```
func handleButtonClicked(sender: UIButton){
     int cellofClickedbutton = sender.tag;
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cell define a protocol:

```
protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
    func buttonTapped()
}
```

and define a delegate variable:

```
weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?
```

Make your `viewController` conform to the defined protocol.

When creating the cell in the `viewController`, assign it the delegate:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

When the button in the cell is tapped, send the delegate appropriate message:

```
delegate?.buttonTapped()
```

In your `viewController` implement the method:

```
func buttonTapped() {
    //do whatever you need
}
```

You can pass as an argument the cell's index, so the `viewController` knows which cell button was tapped.