# How to active button to do action from inside tableview cell (multiple cells)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

How can I make (make offer) button do action inside table cell as the picture:
[this picture of table view include suctions , cells then inside it the button ( make offer ) button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBvF5.png)

I am using this code but it gives an error when I click on it

error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le3VH.png)

this is the code

```
    // tabels functions


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

let view = UIView()

// make section tachuble

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let SW = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

let Ordlbl = UILabel()
Ordlbl.text = "Header"
Ordlbl.frame = CGRect (x: 16, y: 0, width: SW - 16, height: 40)
Ordlbl.font = UIFont(name:"Courier-bold", size: 20.0)
view.addSubview(Ordlbl)

let fromlbl = UILabel()
fromlbl.text = "A12345678"
fromlbl.frame = CGRect (x: 16, y: 20, width: SW - 16, height: 40)
fromlbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
fromlbl.font = UIFont(name:"Courier", size: 20.0)
view.addSubview(fromlbl)

let deslbl = UILabel()
deslbl.text = "- 20 KM ->"
deslbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
deslbl.font = UIFont(name:"Courier", size: 20.0)
deslbl.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: 20,width: SW - 16, height: 40)

view.addSubview(deslbl)

let tolbl = UILabel()
tolbl.text = "B12345678"
tolbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
tolbl.font = UIFont(name:"Courier", size: 20.0)
tolbl.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: 20, width: SW - 16, height: 40)
view.addSubview(tolbl)

return view
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 234/255, green: 238/255, blue: 237/255, alpha: 1.00)

    let SW = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    let deslbl = UILabel()
    deslbl.text = "Order Description :"
    deslbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    deslbl.font = UIFont(name:"Courier-Bold", size: 17.5)
    deslbl.frame = CGRect (x: 16, y: 16, width: SW - 68, height: 40)
    cell.addSubview(deslbl)

    let deslbls = UILabel()
    deslbls.text = "fgwerhioghefrege gergu eriguerg erg uerg peor ger gey gerop gpoergrg er grgporg eropg yergy erpog regy reyg poreg oper goerygpre gyergoer goyer goer goy ergy erg er gyeogp yerop gyoery georgy eroy gpoer gyoer goepr gopre goper gpo ergo ery goper gyroepgy repo gyreopyg repogy peroyg peorg yerpog eropg yeropg yeropg yerop"
    deslbls.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    deslbls.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    deslbls.numberOfLines = 6
    deslbls.font = UIFont(name:"Courier", size: 15.0)
    deslbls.frame = CGRect (x: 16, y: 42, width: SW - 68, height: 100)
    cell.addSubview(deslbls)

    let Timelbl = UILabel()
    Timelbl.text = "60"
    Timelbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    Timelbl.font = UIFont(name:"Courier-Bold", size: 35.0)
    Timelbl.frame = CGRect (x: SW - 70, y: 16, width: 50, height: 50)
    cell.addSubview(Timelbl)

    let Timelbls = UILabel()
    Timelbls.text = "min"
    Timelbls.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    Timelbls.font = UIFont(name:"Courier-Bold", size: 10)
    Timelbls.frame = CGRect (x: SW - 82, y: 35, width: 50, height: 50)
    cell.addSubview(Timelbls)

    let textin = UITextField()
    textin.text = "20"
    textin.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    textin.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    textin.font = UIFont(name:"Courier-Bold", size: 20)
    textin.frame = CGRect (x: 16, y: 150, width: SW - 124, height: 35)
    cell.addSubview(textin)

    let Btin = UIButton()
    Btin.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 127/255, green: 192/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.00)
    Btin.frame = CGRect (x: SW - 100, y: 150, width: 90, height: 35)
    Btin.tag = indexPath.row
    Btin.addTarget(self, action: Selector("printC"), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    cell.addSubview(Btin)


    let Btinlbl = UILabel()
    Btinlbl.text = "Make Offer"
    Btinlbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    Btinlbl.numberOfLines = 2
    Btinlbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    Btinlbl.font = UIFont(name:"Courier-Bold", size: 15)
    Btinlbl.frame = CGRect (x: SW - 95, y: 150, width: 80, height: 35)
    cell.addSubview(Btinlbl)




    return cell
}

func printC(){
    print("ok")
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}

// end table
```

this code is my issue :

```
        let Btin = UIButton()
    Btin.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 127/255, green: 192/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.00)
    Btin.frame = CGRect (x: SW - 100, y: 150, width: 90, height: 35)
    Btin.tag = indexPath.row
    Btin.addTarget(self, action: Selector("printC"), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    cell.addSubview(Btin)
```

and it function is this:

```
    func printC(){
    print("ok")
}
```

Comment: your selector is not proper. try correct one.

Comment: why you not choose storyBoard for designing purpose?

Comment: Correct solution would be to create a custom table view cell and use delegation. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627355/how-to-perform-action-for-a-custom-uitableviewcell-inside-my-viewcontroller?rq=1

Comment: Ok, soryy. Will take closer look next time  @Moritz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Selector("printC")
```

with

```
#selector(YourViewController.printC)
```

And Replace

```
func printC(){
```

with

```
@objc func printC(){
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '(ViewController) -> () -> ()' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: your code         Btin.addTarget(self, action: Selector(ViewController.printC), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

Comment: it should be `#selector` not `Selector `

Comment: now i have 2 errors :  Expected expression in list of expressions  and   Missing argument for parameter 'action' in call Insert ', action: <#Selector#>'

Comment: thanks it works  Btin.addTarget(self, action:#selector(printC), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

Answer (score 0):

Using Callback
Inside the Cell Class Write the below code:

```
var buttonActionCallBack:(()-> Viod)?

 @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
   if let call = buttonActionCallBack {
   call()
   }
}
```

And Inside the CellForRow Write the Bellow code

```
cell.buttonActionCallBack = {
  // Action of Button
}
```

Comment: i did not git it where i should write this i my code ? var buttonActionCallBack:(()-> Viod)?

 @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
   if let call = buttonActionCallBack {
   call()
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3**
in my demo i have two button

1. DoneButton
2. CancelButton

in my tableview cell file i am create one protocol method show in below code

```
@objc protocol MyCellDelegate : NSObjectProtocol{

    @objc optional func didClickDoneButton()
     @objc optional func didClickCancleButton()
}
class MyBookCell: UITableViewCell
{
var delegate:MyCellDelegate?
   override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()




        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    //======================================================================
    //MARK:- Button Done Tapped
    //======================================================================

    @IBAction func btnDoneTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        delegate?.didClickDoneButton?()
    }
    @IBAction func btnCancleTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
       delegate?.didClickCancleButton?()
    }

}
```

In  ViewController

```
import UIKit


class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource ,MyCellDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var MyTable: UITableView!
var MyArray:[String] = ["A" , "B","c"]

 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.MyTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.MyTable.estimatedRowHeight = 80



    }
 //===================================================================
    //MARK:- tableView Delegate Method
    //===================================================================

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return MyArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyBookCell") as! MyBookCell
cell.delegate = self

        return cell
}



func didClickDoneButton()
{
// Your code here
// this is optional method if you don't use then no error found
}
func didClickCancleButton()
{
// Your code here
// this is optional method if you don't use then no error found
}
}
```